# MahApps.Metro: Disabling windows animation

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro) UI for my WPF application. It's a good one and satisfies my needs, but I'd be more happy if somebody told me **how to disable windows animation when they pop up**.

When I call the Show() method, the new window pops up and I see an annoying animation (the content slides from right to left). The effect is similar to another one shown on the picture below (but it shows tabs and content goes left-to-right):

[image: Annoying content animation on popup]

Sample of a dummy form please see below:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="TestProj.Views.TestView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestProj.ViewsModels"
         Height="230" Width="550">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set `WindowTransitionsEnabled="False"` in xaml of the window.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on the equivalent GitHUb issue, the `MetroWindow` control template by default will use a `MetroContentControl` (which has this animation).

You need to edit the template to change it back to a `ContentControl`.

Sample code [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/429#issuecomment-17321036)

Comment: Two weeks ago I reported on the link above that your solution solves the issue, but the new window loses background colour of window title (now everything is white). I provided a simple example to demonstrate the problem, but nobody replied. Could you please at least confirm that you were able to reproduce my problem?

Comment: It turns out that white title background was a bug of last stable build. It's working fine with last beta version.